# Fetch ids of all selected check boxes when one is selected or deselecte

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Currently i'm making filter of products by country. I have list of countries with checkboxes, but i don't know how to properly fetch all ids if some one select a checkbox or de select it. Multiple selections of checkboxes are possible.

This is my HTML

```
<!--checkboxes-->
<fieldset class="m_bottom_15">
  <legend class="default_t_color f_size_large m_bottom_15 clearfix full_width relative">
    <b class="f_left">Filter by: country</b>
  </legend>
<span ng-repeat="c in countries">
   <input type="checkbox" ng-click="filter()" value="{{c.id_country}}" id="{{c.id_country}}"
   class="d_none"><label for="{{c.id_country}}">{{c.country}}</label><br>
</span>
</fieldset>
```

And this is my controller

```
controllers.products = function($scope, categoriesFactory, productsFactory, countriesFactory, $routeParams){
    var cat = $routeParams.param1;
        productsFactory.getProductsInCategory($scope.subCategoryId).then(function(data){
            $scope.products = data;
        });
        countriesFactory.getCountriesList().then(function(data){
            $scope.countries = data.data;
        })
    }).error(function(e){
        console.log(e);
    });
    //Filter products by country ids
    //Don't know how to proceed!!
    $scope.filter = function(id){
        console.log(id);
    }
}
```

My goal is to fetch all checked checkboxes whenever some one click on checkbox and store it in some json object or array so i can use it in api.
If you need any additional information, please let me know and i will provide.

Comment: a plnkr will be nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tie `ngModel` directive with `<input type=checkbox>` elements. Also use `ngChange` instead of `ngClick`. See: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D

For example:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-change="filter()" ng-model="selectedCountries[c.id_country]">
```

Then in your controller:

```
$scope.selectedCountries = {};

$scope.filter = function() {
    console.log(selectedCountries);
}
```

Comment: Good job. Thank you for this